# A case study for search techniques in AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, search-algorithms, didactics

We are teaching an artificial intelligence class and we need a different case study other than geographical maps (the popular example is the map of Romania) to explain the difference between Breadth-first search and Depth-first search solutions. We plan on giving it to the students to use as a semester project.

Comment: The Java aspect is off-topic here, but what examples are suitable for a CS course is on-topic. Your question may be too broad however. What background do the students have? What other classes have they followed previously?

Comment: The differences between the algorithms are easy to show using plain examples (complete graphs, stars, chains, ...). Is there a particular reason you want to use more complicated examples? Which specific differences to you want to highlight?

Comment: The concept is for the students to be able to tell which is the "optimal" solution out of the search methods we are going to use, what we used before is the map of Romania but the professor wants to try other things, but he didn't tell me what exactly!